# linux command to concatenate multiple files with content separated by filenames?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I am looking for a command that will concatenate multiple files in a directory tree with sames having a pattern such that the resulting file has contents of all the files separated by the name(path) of each file. I tried using find -exec and sed but couldn't succeed.Please help.
More specifically I have a directory containing many sub-directories having file named 'test.FAILED'. I want to concatenate all the test.FAILED files separated by their Paths so that I can have a look at all of them at the same time.

Answer (score 5):

```
for i in <pattern>
do
    echo "$i"
    cat "$i"
done > output
```

Comment: <pattern> would be `find`, I think.

Comment: I was thinking that pattern would be something like *.txt; it could be something like `$(find -name "*.txt" -print)`

Comment: Or even better:  `$(find -print|egrep "*\.(php|tpl|html?|js|css|htaccess|sql)$")`

Answer (score 2):

Using (gnu) find:

```
find . -name \*.FAILED -print -exec cat "{}" \;
```